# How execution client get synced after the Merge?

Tags: go-ethereum, the-merge, prysm

I learned that after the Merge, execution client like `geth` only gets new blocks from the consensus client, while I noticed the `geth` client still has its own p2p network and snap sync also works as usual.

So how does the `geth` actually get synced? Is it synced via the p2p network between `geth` clients first, and then only get new blocks from the consensus client (like prysm)?